# How to find rank of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=(a_{ij} )$  be a $100 \times 100$ matrix defined by 
$a_{ij}=i^{2}+j^{2}$
How to find its rank ? Are the rows linearly independent? How to find relation between row or column vectors?
In my book its mentioned that $b_{1j}=a_{1j}=1+j^{2}$ for $i≥2i$, $ b_{ij}=a_{ij}−a_{i}−1$ .Then we can find B by suitable operation on A. Dividing its row by $2i-1$ for $ i≥2 $denoting the reduced matrix by C .RankB= rankC.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: As I mentioned, please show your work in the question and where you are stuck.

Comment: You should include your effort/work in your post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix rank is $\rho=2.$

**Examples**

*Matrices and reduced forms*

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{A}_{2} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 5 \\
 5 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\[3pt]
%
\mathbf{E}_{A} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{A}_{3} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 2 & 5 & 10 \\
 5 & 8 & 13 \\
 10 & 13 & 18 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\[3pt]
%
\mathbf{E}_{A} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 0 & -\frac{5}{3} \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{8}{3} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0}  \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{A}_{4} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 2 & 5 & 10 & 17 \\
 5 & 8 & 13 & 20 \\
 10 & 13 & 18 & 25 \\
 17 & 20 & 25 & 32 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\[3pt]
%
\mathbf{E}_{A} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrr}
 1 & 0 & -\frac{5}{3} & -4 \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{8}{3} & 5 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
$$
$$
  \vdots
$$
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{A}_{6} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
 2 & 5 & 10 & 17 & 26 & 37 \\
 5 & 8 & 13 & 20 & 29 & 40 \\
 10 & 13 & 18 & 25 & 34 & 45 \\
 17 & 20 & 25 & 32 & 41 & 52 \\
 26 & 29 & 34 & 41 & 50 & 61 \\
 37 & 40 & 45 & 52 & 61 & 72 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\[3pt]
%
\mathbf{E}_{A} &= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrrrr}
 1 & 0 & -\frac{5}{3} & -4 & -7 & -\frac{32}{3} \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{8}{3} & 5 & 8 & \frac{35}{3} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\end{align}
$$
$$
  \vdots
$$

*Reduction matrices*

These matrices contain the row operations which transforms $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{E}_{A}$:

$$
 \mathbf{T\,A}= \mathbf{E}_{A}
$$

$$ 
%
\mathbf{T}_{2} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{18} \\
 -\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{29}{18} \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad
%
\mathbf{T}_{3} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{18} & 0 \\
 -\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{29}{18} & 0 \\
 -5 & -\frac{49}{9} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad
%
\mathbf{T}_{4} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{18} & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{29}{18} & 0 & 0 \\
 -5 & -\frac{49}{9} & 1 & 0 \\
 -\frac{17}{2} & -\frac{175}{18} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)%
$$
$$
 \cdots
$$
$$ 
%
\mathbf{T}_{6} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrcccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{18} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{29}{18} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -5 & -\frac{49}{9} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{17}{2} & -\frac{175}{18} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -13 & -\frac{137}{9} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -\frac{37}{2} & -\frac{395}{18} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

**Theory**

Comment: Thnx 4 ur support.